# Python dataframe assign new column using lambda function with 2 variables and if else statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, assign

Setup the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(99)

rows = 10

df = pd.DataFrame ({'A' : np.random.choice(range(0, 2), rows, replace = True),
                    'B' : np.random.choice(range(0, 2), rows, replace = True)})

df


   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  0
3  0  1
4  1  1
5  0  1
6  0  1
7  0  0
8  1  1
9  0  1
```

I would like to add a column 'C' with the value 'X' is df.A and df.B are both 0 and else value 'Y'.

I tried:

```
df.assign(C = lambda row: 'X' if row.A + row.B == 0 else 'Y')
```

but that does not work...

I found other ways to get my results but would like to use `.assign` with a lambda function in this situation.

Any suggestions on how to get assign with lambda working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## No, don't use `lambda`

You can do this vectorised:

```
import numpy as np

df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] + df['B'] == 0, 'X', 'Y')
```

The `lambda` solution has no benefit here, but if you want it...

```
df = df.assign(C=np.where(df.pipe(lambda x: x['A'] + x['B'] == 0), 'X', 'Y'))
```

The *bad* way to use `assign` + `lambda`:

```
df = df.assign(C=df.apply(lambda x: 'X' if x.A + x.B == 0 else 'Y', axis=1))
```

What's wrong with the *bad* way is you are **iterating rows** in a Python-level loop. It's often *worse* than a regular Python `for` loop.

The first two solutions perform **vectorised operations** on contiguous memory blocks, and are processed more efficiently as a result.

Answer (score 2):

Make a simpler condition and apply it to the rows:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'X' if (row.A or row.B) else 'Y', axis = 1)
```

Comment: Nice, but why does this solution not work with df.assign(C = ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Almost there ...

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'X' if row.A + row.B == 0 else 'Y', axis = 1)
```